Bind Observable Collection in WPF to MenuItems as Flat list
I've been trying to sort this out for a few days now and I've hit a wall. I'm trying to bind my collection of Categories to a Menu which then displays each categories list of items in a flat list. How is this possible with Menu/MenuItems?
I've tried using ItemContainerStyle, DataContext...ect. All which have produce some really wonky results. As I'm quite new to WPF i figured i would see what others can share. This seems like it should be simple to do.
The goal:

Here is my .cs
public class DisplayPreset
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

public class DisplayCategory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DisplayPreset> Presets { get; set; }
}

DisplayCategories = new ObservableCollection<DisplayCategory>
{
    new DisplayCategory
    {
        Name = "HD 16:9",
        Presets = new List<DisplayPreset>
        {
            new DisplayPreset { Name = "1280 x 720", Width = 1280, Height = 720 },
            new DisplayPreset { Name = "1920 x 1080", Width = 1920, Height = 1080 },
        }
    },
    new DisplayCategory
    {
        Name = "Square 1:1",
        Presets = new List<DisplayPreset>
        {
            new DisplayPreset { Name = "100 x 100", Width = 100, Height = 100 },
            new DisplayPreset { Name = "200 x 200", Width = 200, Height = 200 },
        }
    }
};


My currently hard coded xaml
<Menu Grid.Column="3" DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <MenuItem >
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Path Style="{StaticResource Icons.ChevronDown}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </MenuItem.Header>

        <MenuItem Header="HD 16:9" IsEnabled="False" FontWeight="SemiBold"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="1280 x 720" />
        <MenuItem Header="1920 x 1080" />

        <MenuItem Header="Square 1:1" IsEnabled="False" FontWeight="SemiBold"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="100 x 100" />
        <MenuItem Header="200 x 200" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>


In my case I tried to use only Menu/MenuItem with Resources and ItemTemplate/DataTemplate.
At the end the Menu looked like this: 
using XAML:
<Menu Foreground="White"
  IsMainMenu="True"
  >
<MenuItem Header="▼" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayCategories}"
          Style="{DynamicResource MenuStyle}"
          Width="165"
          >
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="MenuItemBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <Popup AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MenuItemBorder}"
                       HorizontalOffset="1" VerticalOffset="-1">
                                    <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="Black">
                                        <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Border>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Resources>

    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                           Foreground="Gray"
                           Background="Black"
                           FontWeight="SemiBold"
                           />

                <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Presets}"
                      Foreground="White"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      >
                    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </Style>
                    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                                                    Background="Black"
                                        />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
                </Menu>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>

Hope this helps.

I believe you should use something like a HierarchicalDataTemplate , you can read the documentation here.
public ObservableCollection<DisplayCategory> DisplayCategories { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DisplayCategory>
{
    new DisplayCategory
    {
        Name = "HD 16:9",
        Presets = new ObservableCollection<DisplayPreset>
        {
            new DisplayPreset { Name = "1280 x 720", Width = 1280, Height = 720 },
            new DisplayPreset { Name = "1920 x 1080", Width = 1920, Height = 1080 },
        }
    },
    new DisplayCategory
    {
        Name = "Square 1:1",
        Presets = new ObservableCollection<DisplayPreset>
        {
            new DisplayPreset { Name = "100 x 100", Width = 100, Height = 100 },
            new DisplayPreset { Name = "200 x 200", Width = 200, Height = 200 },
        }
    }
};

xaml:
<Menu Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayCategories}">
    <Menu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Presets}">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" IsEnabled="False" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemTemplate>
</Menu>

